# How to view the process error log for Jenkins Config Save/Apply?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, owasp, zap

I am trying to integrate OWAZP proxy as a postBuild. When i enter all the details in the OWASP config section for MAVEN PROJECT it shows an error as "A Problem Occurred while processing your request" but i am not able to find out the rootcause of this. Please help me in finding out the log file path for this entry".

Answer (score 0):

If it could be a ZAP problem then check the zap.log file : https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/somethings-not-working-what-should-i-do/#check-the-log-file